# Spring-cloud-contract stubrunner.jar change tomcat port

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

I'm currently using the stubrunner.jar found at:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/tree/master/spring-cloud-contract-stub-runner

There doesnt seem to be a way to change the tomcat port (not the stubs port) as in a normal spring boot application. Passing -Dserver.port=7777 is rejected.

Is there a way to change the tomcat hosted port?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it turns out you can.
Was passing --Dserver.port=7777 when it should have been --server.port=7777